# Sum of grouped COUNT IN MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this query

```
SELECT
    country,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tmp_tbl.user_guid) AS number_of_customers
    
FROM complete_tests c INNER JOIN 
      (  SELECT DISTINCT d.dog_guid,  
                u.user_guid, 
                u.country
         FROM dogs d INNER JOIN users u ON d.user_guid = u.user_guid
         WHERE (u.exclude = 0 OR u.exclude IS NULL) 
         AND   (d.exclude = 0 OR d.exclude IS NULL)
      ) 
      AS tmp_tbl ON c.dog_guid = tmp_tbl.dog_guid
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY number_of_customers DESC
```

And I need to add another variable that calculates the percentage of total

when I add

```
number_of_customers/SUM(number_of_customers)
or SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT tmp_tbl.user_guid)) / COUNT(DISTINCT tmp_tbl.user_guid)
```

it gives me error

Comment: `it gives me error` Please post the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytic functions come in handy here.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+:

```sql
SELECT country,
       COUNT(DISTINCT tmp_tbl.user_guid) AS number_of_customers,
       100.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT tmp_tbl.user_guid) /
           SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT tmp_tbl.user_guid)) OVER () AS pct_customers
FROM complete_tests c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT d.dog_guid, u.user_guid, u.country
    FROM dogs d
    INNER JOIN users u ON d.user_guid = u.user_guid
    WHERE (u.exclude = 0 OR u.exclude IS NULL) AND
          (d.exclude = 0 OR d.exclude IS NULL)
) AS tmp_tbl
    ON c.dog_guid = tmp_tbl.dog_guid
GROUP BY
    country
ORDER BY
    number_of_customers DESC;
```